# Insert associated IDs based on string from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, ora-01722

I'm attempting to insert numeric values into a table based on data from two other tables. These numeric values are associated with strings in the table `SL_TERMS`. These strings are used in the other table, `UPLOAD_TEST`, which has the data with which I want to populate `PC_TEST`.

For example, if `UPLOAD_TEST` has the string "environment" and its ID is 1 in the `SL_TERMS table`, I want to insert the value 1 into `PC_TEST`. Here are two examples of the code so far:

```
INSERT INTO PC_TEST (TEST_ID, WHAT_ID, DATA_FORM)
SELECT PC_TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL, t.TERM_ID, e.DATA_FORM FROM SL_TERMS t, UPLOAD_TEST e
WHERE t.TERM_ID IN
(SELECT WHAT FROM UPLOAD_TEST e WHERE e.WHAT = t.TERM_NAME AND t.TERM_NAME = t.TERM_ID); 
--TERM_NAME is the field that has the string associated with the needed ID
```

And

```
INSERT INTO PC_TEST (TEST_ID, WHAT_ID, DATA_FORM)
SELECT PC_TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL, t.TERM_ID, e.DATA_FORM FROM SL_TERMS t
INNER JOIN UPLOAD_TEST e
ON e.WHAT = t.TERM_NAME AND t.TERM_NAME = t.TERM_ID; --using join keyword
```

Both give the **ORA-01722: invalid number** error. The `WHAT_ID` and `TERM_ID` fields are both numeric. Is it possible the strings are not being matched properly? In which case I may need to apply `TRIM` and/or `LOWER` functions to the strings from `UPLOAD_TEST`. Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

`e.WHAT` and `t.TERM_NAME` are the same fields with a one to many relationship. So, in `SL_TERMS`, the value `TERM_NAME = 'environment'` exists once and so does its associated `TERM_ID = 1`. It may exist in several records in `UPLOAD_TEST`.

The flow is therefore `e.WHAT` (string) --> `t.TERM_NAME` (string) --> `t.TERM_ID` (number).

The reason I equated `t.TERM_NAME` to `t.TERM_ID` is because I need that associated ID when I call `e.WHAT` (`t.TERM_NAME`). I didn't know if this is the correct way to do it (it doesn't seem like it), so if there's a way to call the ID (`TERM_ID`) from the string (`TERM_NAME`), that's what I need.

Comment: Are you sure about `t.TERM_NAME = t.TERM_ID`? You said `TERM_ID` is a number, but it doesn't sound like `TERM_NAME` will be a number too. Please add all three table structures and some sample data to your question, but I suspect that clause just needs to be removed.

Comment: Let me know if my edit isn't explicit enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't know if this is the correct way to do it (it doesn't seem like it), so if there's a way to call the ID (TERM_ID) from the string (TERM_NAME), that's what I need.

It isn't the correct way to do it. You don't need to call the ID from the name string; they are in the same row in the table, so the ID is just available once you've identified the row by its ID.

So you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO PC_TEST (TEST_ID, WHAT_ID, DATA_FORM)
SELECT PC_TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL, t.TERM_ID, e.DATA_FORM
FROM SL_TERMS t
INNER JOIN UPLOAD_TEST e
ON e.WHAT = t.TERM_NAME;
```

You're getting the error because when you include the `t.TERM_NAME = t.TERM_ID` clause Oracle is having to try to convert every identified row's `TERM_NAME` to a number in order to compare it with the numeric ID. Unless the names consist only of numeric characters, that will cause the error you're seeing. In your example you're implicitly trying to to `to_number('environment') = 1`, and that implicit `to_number()` will throw ORA-01722 because 'environment' is not a number.

Arguably Oracle could have chosen to convert the number to a string, but even if it did do that ([and it won't](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#g195937) - "When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value."), the ID and name are still not going to be the same, so you'd get no data instead of an error.

Comment: I tried it right after I understood your comment and it worked. _You don't need to call the ID from the name string; they are in the same row in the table, so the ID is just available once you've identified the row by its ID._ This isn't what I was sure of. PLSQL isn't my main so sometimes I don't know what's going on under the hood. Thanks for the correct answer and all the under-the-hood information. Marked as correct.